# How to set AlarmManager every 2:00 am PendingIntent on Android?

Tags: android

I want to reboot the device when the app is running, at 2 am.

so I use `PendingIntent` and `AlarmManager`

MainActivity.onCreate

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Intent intent = new Intent("REBOOT_START_INTENT");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONT_SHOW);

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

Manifest.xml

```
<receive android:name="RebootAlarm">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="REBOOT_START_INTENT"/>
    <intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

RebootAlarm.class

```
static Process rebootProcess;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        rebootProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot"});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this source,  when app start. will always execute in `RebootAlarm.class`

so, when app start. will always execute reboot.
why occur this problem?

I want only execute reboot on 2:00 am every day.

How to fix this problem?

thanks.

Comment: You're not accounting for the possibility that 2:00am has already passed today, in which case you're setting an alarm in the past, and it fires immediately, give or take a few seconds.

Comment: The answer on the linked duplicate shows how to check the alarm time against the current time, and add a day if it's already passed today.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks you